# How do I convert a logical variable to factor in Rattle

Tags: r, rattle

I am using Rattle to run `randomForest` against my training data set. One of the variables has values `FALSE` and `TRUE`.

```
     > str(mydata)
     'data.frame':  421570 obs. of  2 variables:
     $ Trial       : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
     $ IsHoliday   : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
```

I am able to convert the same to a factor in R.

```
     > mydata$IsHoliday <- factor(mydata$IsHoliday)
     > str(mydata)
     'data.frame':  421570 obs. of  2 variables:
     $ Trial       : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
     $ IsHoliday   : Factor w/ 2 levels "FALSE","TRUE": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

When I write the `data.frame` to a CSV and load it using `Rattle`, again I am seeing it as logical only. Due to this, I am getting the error, `Error in na.roughfix.data.frame(x) + na.roughfix only works for numeric or factor`

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like automatic type conversion - maybe try `mydata$IsHoliday <- factor(ifelse(mydata$IsHoliday,"yes","no"))` to force entries to look nothing like a logical - or if you have access to the function that's reading in the data, look at the `colClasses` setting to force the csv to be read in as you wish: `read.csv(..., colClasses=c("integer","character")...`

Comment: I dont have the access to the function that reads CSV in `rattle`. I am just browsing the file and executing.

Comment: OK, so you'll probably have to try the `ifelse` solution - does that work?

Comment: Re comment about "access to the function".. have a look at the log tab in Rattle for the actual code that is being executed. You can take that code and modify to suit the read.csv as suggested here to load the data into R, then in the Data tab choose the RDataSet option to access this dataset within Rattle, and build the forest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should try including "as"

```
mydata$IsHoliday=as.factor(mydata$IsHoliday)
```